# How to clear the numeric type textboxes on Button click in View model using Icommand

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

What should I write for the Integer type Id and Age? How should I clear the fields in the form?
**Xaml Code**

```
    <Button Command="{Binding CmdClear}" Content="Clear"></Button>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public ICommand CmdClear
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand(ClearFields);
            }
        }

        private void ClearFields()
        {
            Id =;
          Name = string.Empty;
            Age = ;
            Country = string.Empty;
            Active = string.Empty;

        }
```

Comment: Set the source property values to '0' or'-1' if '0' is a valid value. Then use an IValueConverter to convert this values to an empty string or some placeholder text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it nullable field like `Id?` and `Age?`.
Or
you can set that field property in XAML `TargetNullValue=''`

Comment: I cant add any TargetNullProperty to the Xaml Code. The Field is actually numeric TextBox. And Can you please elaborate on how I can make the variables Nullable?

Comment: I got the answer.Thank you